# IActionFilter class can only find physical attributes, not ones added in GlobalFilters config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, custom-attributes, action-filter

Using the following classes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
}

public class OrderItemCountFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var attribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute), true);
        var attribute2 = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute),true);
        if (attribute.All(o => o.GetType() != typeof (OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute)))
        {
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception("It worked!");
    }

}
```

And the following FilterConfig:

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Container container)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());


        filters.Add(new OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute());
        filters.Add(container.GetInstance<OrderItemCountFilter>();
    }
}
```

The globally added OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute is not found by `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute),true);`. However, if I add it manually to the action, then I can use it.

I've been at this for 2 days and I've made no progress. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing here or a series of properties I can access to visit the globally added OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GlobalFilters collection is accessible at `GlobalFilters.Filters`

You could find your attribute in the global collection with code like the following: `var filters = GlobalFilters.Filters.Select(v => v.Instance).OfType<OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute>();`